AngularJS, show array value according to another array current position
In javascript, there are two arrays, their length are equal, but the length is not known, based on some db value. for example
colName=['col1','col2','col3'];
fieldValue=['abc','def','ghi'];

or
colName=['col1','col2','col3', 'col4'];
fieldValue=['abc','def','ghi', 'lmn'];

or
colName.length = x, fieldValue.length = x
where x is variable.
then in html, using angularjs I want to display the colName value based on the position of current retrieving fieldValue position.
e.g.
<tr ng-repeat="fieldValue in form.fieldValue track by $index">
    <td> {{colName[{{$index}}]}}</td>
    <td> {{fieldValue}} </td> 
</tr>

Of course this part is fail
<td> {{colName[{{$index}}]}}</td>

so how to show the colName[x] based on the current fieldValue position?
Expected Result: (no.of colX is dynamic)
col1 abc
col2 def
col3 ghi

In AngularJS, to display the corresponding value of the colName array based on the position of the current element in the fieldValue array, you do not need to use {{$index}} to directly index the colName array. On the contrary, you can leverage the feature of ng repeat, which already tracks the index of the current iteration internally.
The correct approach is to directly use the corresponding index of the colName array in the ng repeat instruction, without the need for {{$index}}. In ng repeat, AngularJS automatically pairs the current element with the corresponding element of the colName array each time the fieldValue array is iterated.
Here is an example of the correct HTML code:
<tr ng-repeat="(index, fieldValue) in form.fieldValue track by $index">
    <td> {{colName[index]}}</td>
    <td> {{fieldValue}} </td> 
</tr>

In this example, (index, fieldValue) is the deconstruction of ng repeat iteration form. fieldValue. Index is the index of the current element in the fieldValue array, and fieldValue is the current element itself. Track by $index ensures that iterations remain synchronized even if the order of elements in two arrays changes.
In this way, eachtag will display the value corresponding to the current fieldValue element in the colName array.
So, if the colName array and fieldValue array have the same length and order, the above code will work as expected. If the array length is different or the order is inconsistent, the result cannot be guaranteed, so it is ensured that these two arrays are synchronized in practical applications.

What is the meaning of "(index, fieldValue) is the deconstruction of ng repeat iteration form. "? and how many variable can be defined within the ()? seem documentations has not mentioned these usage, thanks.

In AngularJS, the ng repeat instruction can accept a deconstructive assignment, which allows you to directly extract indexes and values from iterations. Here, (index, fieldValue) is an example of deconstruction assignment, which is a feature of ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) that can be used in JavaScript to extract variables from arrays or objects.
Here is a detailed explanation:
Ng repeat="(index, fieldValue) in form. fieldValue track by $index": The meaning of this code is that for each element in the form. fieldValue array, ng repeat will perform one iteration. In each iteration, it assigns the index of the current element to the variable index and the value of the current element to the variable fieldValue.
Deconstruct parentheses in assignment: parentheses allow you to define one or more variables that will receive corresponding values from each iteration. In this example, there are two variables: index and fieldValue.
There is actually no limit to how many variables can be defined in parentheses, as long as you follow the following rules:
You must provide a variable name for each position of the deconstruction.
The number of variables must match the number of elements in the structure you want to deconstruct (in this case, the array).
For example:
<-- If your array is composed of two elements, such as [1,'a '], [2,'b'],...] -->
<tr ng repeat="([index, name], fieldValue) in someArray track by $index">
<td>{{index}}</td>
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{fieldValue}}</td>
</tr>

In the above code, you deconstruct each subarray in someArray and assign the first element (index) to the variable index, and the second element (name) to the variable name.
As for the documentation, indeed, the official documentation of AngularJS may not explicitly mention this form of deconstruction assignment, as it is a feature of ES6 rather than unique to AngularJS. However, due to the widespread use of JavaScript expressions in AngularJS, this usage is completely effective in AngularJS applications.
Finally, your understanding of array synchronization is correct. If the length and order of the colName and fieldValue arrays are inconsistent, there may be problems displaying the data. In practical applications, you should ensure that these two arrays are synchronized to avoid potential errors.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="yourApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in fieldValue track by $index">
            <td>{{ colName[$index] }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);

        app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.colName = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']; // 动态加载
            $scope.fieldValue = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']; // 动态加载
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

